# Teamcity Git private Submodule checkout fails

Tags: git, teamcity, bitbucket, git-submodules, teamcity-9.0

TeamCity unable to checkout git projects with private git submodules (projects themselves are private and accessed with username/password and use same credentails for submodules), all source is stored on bitbucket and accessed over HTTPS. TeamCity is able to using the same VCS root checkout other projects without submodules just fine (so im happy credentails/proxy issues are not the issue).

the error returned is:

```
Failed to build patch for build #19 {build id=209, buildTypeId=CI_BC_123},
VCS root: "BitBucket VCS" {instance id=192, parent internal id=11, parent id=BITBUCKET_VCS, description: "https://bitbucket.org/team123/main-repo.git#"}, due to error: 'build patch' command failed.

stderr: Cannot fetch the 'https://username123@bitbucket.org/team123/sharedAsssetsRepo.git//username123@bitbucket.org/team123/sharedAsssetsRepo.git' repository used as a submodule at the 'repo/SharedAssets' path in the 'https://bitbucket.org/team123/main-repo.git' repository in the ba90b0c96170b1abf5af2322069662c7b541d908 commit
```

and the submodules as follows

```
[submodule "repo/SharedAssets"]
   path =repo/SharedAssets
   url = ../sharedAsssetsRepo.git
[submodule "repoB"]
   path = resouceB
   url = ../resourceB.git
```

TC v 9.0.4 (build 32407) on Windows Server 2012 using server side checkout (agent reside on same server)

What I've tried:

- confirmed that `git clone --recursive` from powershell pulls down the repo and submodules correctly
- convert submodule paths from relative to absolute
- set git global proxy settings

I am unable to use agent side checkout at all (agents are on the same box with mysysgit installed) `fatal: unable to access ' <<repo>> ': Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Timed out` which is odd seeing as the server client can connect as can git from PowerShell (git path in teamcity is set the same as git PATH in windows).